# nested foreach() get a proper result

Tags: php, foreach

I have simple nested `foreach()` but I do not get what I thought it will.

here is the full code:

```
public function namelist() {
      return array('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename');
}

public function nameRequest($namelist) { // either lastname, firstname or middlename
      switch($namelist) {
            case 'lastname':
                $request = array('ramirez', 'corazon', 'gonzaga');
            break;
            case 'firstname':
                $request = array('michael', 'michaela', 'angel');
            break;
            case 'middlename':
                $request = array('osaka', 'oscar', 'roxas');
            break;
      }
   return $request;
}
```

I want a result like this:

```
Lastname: ramirez, corazon, gonzaga
Firstname: michael, michaela, angel
Middlename: osaka, oscar, roxas
```

But when I tried to code it like this:

```
public function fullname() {
      $namelist = '';
      $namedata = '';
      $namelists = self::namelist();

      foreach ($namelists as $names) {
             $namelist .= $names . ': ';
             $namerequest = self::nameRequest($names);

             foreach ($namerequest as $namerequests){
                    $namedata .= $namerequests . ',';
             }
      }
      return $namelist . ': ' . $namedata; 
}
```

it returns:

```
lastname: firstname: middlename: ramirez, corazon, gonzaga, michael, michaela, angel, osaka, oscar, roxas
```

So how can I solved this ?

Comment: Your question title based on your question asked is misleading.

Comment: why did a get downvotes?

Comment: thanks i will edit my title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some misplaced statements:

```
<pre>
<?php
function namelist() {
    return array('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename');
}
function nameRequest($namelist) { // either lastname, firstname or middlename
    switch($namelist) {
        case 'lastname':
        $request = array('ramirez', 'corazon', 'gonzaga');
        break;
        case 'firstname':
        $request = array('michael', 'michaela', 'angel');
        break;
        case 'middlename':
        $request = array('osaka', 'oscar', 'roxas');
        break;
    }
    return $request;
}
function fullname() {
    $namelist = '';
    $namelists = namelist();
    foreach ($namelists as $names) {
        $namedata = ''; // moved
        $namerequest = nameRequest($names);
        foreach ($namerequest as $namerequests){
            $namedata .= $namerequests . ',';
        }
        $namelist .= $names . ': ' . $namedata . "\n"; // new
    }
    return $namelist; // modified
}
echo fullname();
?>
```

Note: I removed the object orientation for my test.
Test: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v82x-czc4

Also consider using `implode()` instead of your inner `foreach`. It is shorter and will solve the trailing `,` issue you still have.

Answer (score 1):

This would make more sense, if you update your loop:

```
 public function fullname() {
          $namelist = '';
          $namedata = '';
          $namelists = self::namelist();
          $temp = '';

          foreach ($namelists as $names) {
                 $namerequest = self::nameRequest($names);

                 foreach ($namerequest as $namerequests){
                        $namedata .= $namerequests . ',';
                 }

                 $temp .= $names . ': ' . $namedata.'<br/>';
          }
          return $temp; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,it is very simple and easiest and short from above code.Because foreach loop run 2 time on above code so it affect execution time,so please try this

```
<?php
public function namelist() {
      return array('lastname', 'firstname', 'middlename');
}

public function nameRequest($namelist) { // either lastname, firstname or middlename
      switch($namelist) {
            case 'lastname':
                $request = array('ramirez', 'corazon', 'gonzaga');
            break;
            case 'firstname':
                $request = array('michael', 'michaela', 'angel');
            break;
            case 'middlename':
                $request = array('osaka', 'oscar', 'roxas');
            break;
      }
   return $request;
}

public function fullname() {
      $namelists = self::namelist();
      $fullname = '';
      foreach ($namelists as $names) {
          $namerequest = self::nameRequest($names);
          $nameIs = implode(",", $namerequest);
          $fullname .= $names.": " . $nameIs . "<br>";
      }
      return $fullname;
}

echo fullname();
?>
```

Comment: you can replace echo with return,if you have any problem

Comment: @Sanjay Dhiman It obviously is a school exercise, so we help with problems on the work done and give tips, not code in their place.

Comment: Thanks for advice,i will follow